# Error 1215: Why is it happening?

Tags: mysql

I am confused as to why error 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint is occurring in my code.  Does anybody have any ideas?

The first four tables create themselves fine, but the error is thrown when I try to create the Stars table.  I am not sure what's going wrong, as the keys being referenced are primary keys and so  they must be unique and non-null.  Plus, those keys exist as the previous tables have been created first.  It might just be a stupid mistake I made, but its better to have fresh eyes look at it, right?

This database is simplistic as it is because I'm doing it for a school assignment.

```
create table MovieExec
(
execName varchar(40),
certNum numeric(30, 0),
address varchar(50),
networth real,
primary key(execName),
unique key(certNum)
);

create table Stud
(
studName varchar(30),
address varchar(50),
presCNum numeric(30, 0),
primary key(studName),
foreign key (presCNum) references MovieExec(certNum)
);

create table MovieStar(
starName varchar(30),
address varchar(50),
gender varchar(1), 
birthdate date,
primary key(starName)
);

create table Movies
(
movieTitle varchar(30),
movieYear numeric(4,0), 
length numeric(3,0),
genre varchar(30),
studioName varchar(30),
producerCNum numeric(30, 0),
primary key (movieTitle, movieYear),
foreign key (producerCNum) references MovieExec(certNum),
foreign key (studioName) references Stud(studName)
);

create table Stars
(
movieTitle varchar(30), 
movieYear numeric(4,0),
starName varchar(30),
primary key (movieTitle, movieYear, starName),
foreign key (movieTitle) references Movies(movieTitle),
foreign key (movieYear) references Movies(movieYear),
foreign key (starName) references MovieStar(starName)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a composite foreign key for the title and the year:

```
foreign key (movieTitle, movieYear) references Movies(movieTitle, movieYear),
foreign key (starName) references MovieStar(starName)
```

It should be composite because that's the exact PK of `Movies` table and that's the only `UNIQUE` combination there currently available.

Then as @CBroe mentioned in their answer it would be a good idea to index the `Stars.starName` column.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html:

> “[…] in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the *first columns* in the same order”

In your `Movies` table, you only have a primary key on the combination `(movieTitle, movieYear)` – but `movieYear` is not the first column in that key, and therefor

```
foreign key (movieYear) references Movies(movieYear)
```

in your CREATE statement for the `stars` table fails.

Add a key on `Movies.movieYear` – then creating a foreign key referencing that column on the `stars` table will work.

FYI: MySQL has a [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/year.html) data type – you should use that, instead of a NUMERIC for your movie year.

---

And you are mixing singular and plural in your table names. Convention is to use the singular of the object that a table holds as table name; but at least you should try and be consistent with your naming scheme.